# Slow overall performance in Community

Tags: community, performance, bootstrap

I have struggled with slow performance in my Community for years now.  It is getting worse.  We use a Community for our publicly facing website & for our portal.  The slow performance is on all pages  regardless of whether any queries are being called.  A Salesforce partner today found that Salesforce is rendering information for all of the site's pages in the bootstrap.js file that is taking over 9 seconds to load.  After deleting about 40 of our site's pages in a test environment, the site's speed improved.  This is not an acceptable solution because we need a lot of pages in our Community and will continue to need more.  We also use a lot of Salesforce's security (audiences) to hide/display pages/components.

Is anyone familiar with this & what can be done about this.  If this can't be resolved, we will need to move off of Community as our website/portal.  We need to continue to add pages & cannot continue to have the slow performance we are seeing much less it getting worse.

Comment: Apparently you can get a significant speed boost (around 30% I think ) if you use a lwc template. However, at present, I don't think it the new templates do audiences (which I also use). They are pretty handy! Have you checked for any other timing issues in the network tab in the developer console of your browsesr? You might find some improvements there. Also, you can get an external CDN to host the site, which is supposed to improve things.

Comment: A digital experience, aka Community, is what is called a single page app, as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm), hence all pages delivered up front. As Casper Harmer said, Salesforce provide a very basic and light weight option using the Lightning Web Runtime, covered [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro.htm) but this is really only suitable for pro code development as the template exposes next to no component options at all.

Comment: See if there are any caching options to improve performance for initial loading after first visit (I haven't found anything myself as yet).

Comment: @PhilW  I have the caching option enabled.  While it is supposed to improve performance, I didn't see any.

Comment: @CasparHarmer - I have a significant # of aura components in use in my Community.  I am not opposed to converting everything to LWC, but I am looking for a guarantee that performance would be good - what people would expect on a professional website.  I don't want to invest in converting only to find continued performance problems.

Comment: @Phil - are you saying that Community is not meant to serve as a professional website with 50+ pages?  I have worked with both 7Summits and Affirma (2 major Salesforce partners) on developing our Community.  Neither company gave any inkling that we shouldn't be using Community to develop our public/portal website.  Am I misunderstanding that you seem to be saying that the Community is functioning slowly as expected with a lot of pages with security on them?  We have invested a lot of money in this solution.

Comment: I don't have the experience with a large scale digital experience (I've only created with 5-10 pages). If you use Aura extensively, you should definitely use LWC as these are much, much more performant, however you should [edit] your question to clarify the scale and content of the community since on re-reading you imply the performance is poor, not just on loading but executing activities within the pages, and that means it isn't the SPA nature of the community that is the issue but rather the components within the pages. You should consider profiling the site using your browser's inspector.

Comment: The Salesforce site can have that many pages. We are using one. Our community was also slow but the slowness is because our community is completely custom. We have CDN enabled. We occasionally run it through Google pagespeed insights to check what is causing the slowness and also use the Community optimizer extension in Chrome.

Comment: @manjit5190  Can you elaborate on your slowness situation?  Is it still slow?  We are using a custom Lightning template for our Community developed by 7Summits.  It is their  Digital Experience template.  Did enabling CDN improve your situation?  By what percent would you say?

Comment: We are using the custom service template in public facing community. It is a very UI heavy community with about 50 different pages and 70 LWC + 20 Aura components. The home page took about 10 seconds to load .We reviewed it and noticed there were couple of factors `1.` Initial load time - Enabled CDN to reduce some time there. `2.` Preloading resources in global markup. `3.` Enabling priority loading (OOTB). `4.` Combined the XHR calls to make sure at most 6 calls can be made on the page. `5.` Stopped making avoidable changes in render-callback to reduce re-rendering cycles.

Comment: `6.` Marked all static resources as public cacheable. `7.` Implemented caching (platform) for some data which won't change frequently. `8. ` Optimized image sizes. `9.` Stopped using full page spinners (perception for end user).  All these led to 50% reduction in loading time. Now the site loads in 5 seconds maximum. We are still optimizing. Movement to BYO (Non LWR) template is on our list next if a switch is possible .

Comment: @manjit5190 Thanks...  we are in almost the same scenario that you started with.  It is taking about 10 seconds for our home page to load.  It sounds like you did a lot of work to get the 50% load time deduction.  Would you say your site now has the load experience that most users would expect from a professional site?  Even 5 seconds seems long.  I am hesitant to invest the time and money in making the changes you described to not end up with a very fast site.

Comment: @manjit5190  In my case, we will continue to need more pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126080/discussion-between-manjit5190-and-michele-kleinhomer).

Comment: @manjit5190 There is some good information in your comments above - I think it makes a valid answer to this question. You should turn it into one. :)

Comment: Thanks @CasparHarmer. I added it as an answer

Comment: @CasparHarmer  Caspar...while Manjit5190 provided some ways to attempt to improve the speed of the Community, he even indicates that the performance seen of ~5 seconds to load a page is unacceptable.  I have a case open with Salesforce about this.  I want to know if it is possible to get professional level speed with a Community that has over 50+ pages and a lot of security on the different pages.

Comment: I don't want to invest any more time/money in this if I can't get assurance that the speed can be good under these circumstances.  I understand there are many variables that can come into play, but I want to know in general if performance can be good with even over 100+ pages because that is definitely in our not-so-far-off future.

Answer (score 3):

We have a similar open community/experience and were facing slowness issues. The slowness is because our community is completely custom. We do have CDN enabled and we occasionally run Google page speed insights to check what is causing the slowness and also use the Community optimizer extension in Chrome.

We are using the custom service template in public facing community. It is a very UI heavy community with about 50 different pages and 70 LWC + 20 Aura components + 6 different audiences. The home page took about 10 seconds to load.

We reviewed it and noticed there were couple of factors

1. Initial load time - Enabled CDN to reduce some time there.
2. Preloading resources in global markup.
3. Enabling priority loading (OOTB).
4. Combined the XHR calls to make sure at most 6 calls can be made on the page.
5. Stopped making avoidable changes in render-callback to reduce re-rendering cycles.
6. Marked all static resources as public cacheable.
7. Implemented caching (platform) for some data which won't change frequently.
8. Optimized image sizes.
9. Stopped using full page spinners (perception for end user).

All these led to 50% reduction in loading time. Now the site loads in 5 seconds maximum. We are still optimizing to reduce it to 2-3 seconds. Movement to BYO (Non LWR) template is on our list next if a switch is possible and we are also looking into converting Aura components to LWC.

I would suggest to run your community through Lighthouse (built into most browsers)/[page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and [Salesforce community extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-community-page/alkcnclapbnefkodhbkpifdkceldogka) to find what is causing the slowness. The bootstrap js would add to initial load times but there are lot of other factors, perception being one of them.

[image]